# Saving a stream to a .wav file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wav

I've pulled a wave file from an online service I use and am now trying to save the returned stream. This is my code so far:

```
        Using wavout = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
                'error begins on next line
                wavout.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create("output.wav")
                Dim buf(65536) As Byte
                Dim len As Integer = 0
                While ((len = wavout.Read(buf, 0, 65536)) > 0)
                    fs.Write(buf, 0, len)
                    fs.Close()
                End While
        End Using
```

When I run the code it comes up with an exception saying 'this stream does not support seek operations'.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some streams doesn’t support seeking. You can know it by a test such as “CanSeek”.
I’ve changed some lines in your code giving that as an answer to help you understanding the mechanism.

```
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create("yoururlhere.com"), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Using wavout As IO.Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

        'usnig this test you can avoid exceptions on seeking
        If wavout.CanSeek Then
            wavout.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        End If

        Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create("output.wav")

            Dim buf(1024 * 8) As Byte
            Dim len As Integer

            Do
                len = wavout.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
                If len = 0 Then Exit Do
                fs.Write(buf, 0, len)
            Loop

        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, really appreciate your help! Glad I was at least in the right ballpark for this one. Thanks

Comment: Our knowledge are nothing without using them helping community. You are welcome.